# Is there a bug with min="0" in jquery validation? Or am I overlooking something?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

jQuery validation seems to work fine with `min="1"` and `min="-1"`, but not with `min="0"`. Consider this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/RAJZX/2/). It appropriately objects to a value of -5 in the first `input` element and in the third, but accepts a -5 in the second one, where `min="0"`.

[image: -1 and 1 are fine. 0 is not]

Is this a bug in jQuery validation or am I overlooking something?

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="negativeone" min="-1"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="zero" min="0"/>    
  <br/>
<input type="text" name="one" min="1" />
</form> 
<button id="event2">Test</button>
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({
    });

    $('#event2').on('click', function () {
        $('#myform').valid();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that the right fiddle? It doesn't reflect your code...

Comment: Works as intended [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MgvRn/). What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Testing in Chrome v28 on OSX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question:

"No", you're not overlooking anything, and "Yes", this appears to be a bug.

Look at these two identical jsFiddles, where only the version is different...

**jQuery Validate v1.10** (no bug):  http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MgvRn/

**jQuery Validate v1.11.1** (bug):  http://jsfiddle.net/MgvRn/1/

Also, this only appears to be an issue when using HTML5 validation attributes.

Until the plugin is fixed, a workaround would be to just declare the rule inside `.validate()`.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        zero: {
            min: 0
        }
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO** (v1.11.1):  http://jsfiddle.net/MgvRn/2/

---

I suggest that you report this bug on the developer's Github page:

[https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues?page=1&state=open)

Comment: Reported, as https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/854, using your fiddles