# jquery validation built-in rules not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm attempting to validate a function with jquery validation (http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

The validate function gets called and the following ruleset (abbreviated) gets applied.

```
$('#sampleParameters2').validate({
        rules: {
            P00003: {
                custom_float: true,
                required: true },
            P00004: {
                min: 0 },
            P00009: {custom_float: true}
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { ......
```

If I run afoul of the custom rule I've created, custom_float, I get the message I expect.

But if I run afoul of the 'required' or 'min' rules, the submit handler still gets called and I get no messages.

The inputs are all of the following format:

```
<input class="number" type="text" name="P00003" id="P00003" placeholder="in feet" onChange="save_data(this.name,this.value)">
```

I could get around the min issue using html5 validation (just setting min=0 in the form) but unfortunately, that's a known bug. ([Is there a bug with min="0" in jquery validation? Or am I overlooking something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255741/is-there-a-bug-with-min-0-in-jquery-validation-or-am-i-overlooking-something))

I'd assume it was just that bug... but in the above link, they actually suggest that setting min:0 in the rules is the way to get around it.  Additionally, the 'required' doesn't work either.  Only the custom rule (so I know the problem isn't in the validate call).

EDIT:  due to comment, I'm including my custom float rule. (which was written to see if a custom rule worked)

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom_float", function (value, element) {
        return value.match(/^([+-]?(?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*)|)$/);//Accepts only floats or blank space
    }, "Please enter a valid float number");
```

Also note that to solve the min:0 not working problem and move on to bigger fish, I simply wrote another custom rule and assigned it... and it works.  That said, I'd like to figure out what the true problem is and do it the 'right' way:

```
$.validator.addMethod("positive", function (value, element) {
            if(value==null || value.trim()=="") {
                return true;
            } else
                return (value>0);
    }, "Please enter a value greater than or equal to zero");
```

Comment: Could you share your custom_float rule which you have created or try setting required='required' in the HTML input tag instead?

Comment: That bug in jquery validate about `min:0` is fixed in version 1.13.1, and possibly before that.